# How to use DataDog is_match function with log attributes

Tags: alert, datadog

I want to use Datadog `is_match` function to get alerts based on status code (attribute). As shown below, the status code is included in both the log message and the log stack attribute.

[image: DataDog - Logs]

However, when I use the `is_match` function like below, I get a warning.

[image: DataDog - Log Message]

[image: DataDog - Log Stack Attribute]

Is there a recommended way to do this?